Issue using highchart with vite plugin federation in reactjs
I'm not able to use highcharts with vite plugin federation in reactjs for micro front end.
Error in chrome console is
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
    at createFiberFromTypeAndProps (chunk-373CG7ZK.js?v=da962c3f:20440:23)
    at createFiberFromElement (chunk-373CG7ZK.js?v=da962c3f:20461:23)
    at reconcileSingleElement (chunk-373CG7ZK.js?v=da962c3f:10511:31)
    at reconcileChildFibers2 (chunk-373CG7ZK.js?v=da962c3f:10548:43)
    at reconcileChildren (chunk-373CG7ZK.js?v=da962c3f:14288:37)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (chunk-373CG7ZK.js?v=da962c3f:14984:13)
    at beginWork (chunk-373CG7ZK.js?v=da962c3f:15912:22)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (chunk-373CG7ZK.js?v=da962c3f:3672:22)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (chunk-373CG7ZK.js?v=da962c3f:3697:24)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (chunk-373CG7ZK.js?v=da962c3f:3731:39)

Package.json content is
 {
  "name": "remote",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --port 5173 --strictPort",
    "build": "tsc -b && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview --port 4000 --strictPort",
    "deploy": "npm run build & npm run preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "highcharts": "^11.4.8",
    "highcharts-react-official": "^3.2.1",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.9.0",
    "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation": "^1.3.6",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint": "^9.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.1.0-rc.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.9",
    "globals": "^15.9.0",
    "typescript": "^5.5.3",
    "typescript-eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "vite": "^5.4.1"
  }
}

When i run remote application as standalone it works fine but when using as micro front end it does not work

Hi @T. Kong, This problem can be related to the way you import the HighcartsReact component. Please try to use import {HighchartsReact} from "highcharts-react-official" instead of import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official", or the opposite.
